# Minimum degree of freedom for which t-dis and n-dist are equal

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to find the smallest degree of freedom for which the 0.9 quantile of the t dist equals the .9 quantile of the standard normal dist (both rounded to 3 decimal places). I have following equation where I am varying the df from 1 to 1000 to manually check the minimum df. I would like to know if the equation is correct?

```
d <- c(1:1000)
round(qt(0.9, df=d),3) - round(qnorm(0.9),3))
```

Comment: Start by noting that `qt` is vectorized. Your instruction returns a vector of length 1000. The rest should be immediate.

Comment: qt will return a vector of 1000 values each df which is what i want. But my question is that the above equation is the right interpretation of the problem?

Comment: I don't believe there's another interpretation. Maybe you could also use `abs`, since it's a distance. In this case the results would be the same but theoretically it would be better.